# How to make a session with Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I tried making a login and a registration system with Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore.

I can do a simple registration and also i can login and the data that i needed is saved in Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore.

[image]

[image]

The login session for Firebase Authentication is fine.
But the problem is i cant get the current user information about the user that i already saved in Cloud Firestore. I can access it, i just cant saved it to make a session.

So how can i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate. have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55350678/how-do-i-save-user-session-using-sharedpreferences-in-cloud-firestore-when-im-n

Comment: Please edit the question to show what code have you tried that isn't working the way you expect. Is there an error message?

Comment: I have created a [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseApp) in which I have implemented Firebase Authentication using a Google account and Cloud Firestore. Might solve your problem.

Comment: Please also provide what Doug Stevenson asked for.

Comment: Im sorry, my code right now is a mess. I "brute forcing" some code and even have 3 login for 3 different to force them have the level they choose but all user can be at all level because of this.